# Display Image JSP MYSQL JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am using MVC2 in developing a simple app.
Below is my code to perform retrieving image task. 
It works but is this an efficient solution or will it reduce web performance?

`RS_SELECT.getBytes(LECTURER_PROFILE_PICTURE`) or should I use `RS_SELECT.getStream()`?

View JSP:

```
<body>
    <img src="lecturerController?email=blabla@hotmail.com" />
</body>
```

Java Servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
@WebServlet("/lecturerController")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
public class lecturerController extends HttpServlet {

LecturerDAO dao;

public lecturerController() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    dao = new LecturerDAO();
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Lecturer lecturer = new Lecturer();
    lecturer = dao.getLecturer(request.getParameter("email"));

    response.setContentType(lecturer.getProfilePictureCT());
    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    output.write(lecturer.getProfilePicture());
    output.flush();
}
```

Java DAO:

```
public Lecturer getLecturer (String email) {
    Lecturer lecturer;
    PreparedStatement PS_SELECT;
    Statement ST_SELECT;
    ResultSet RS_SELECT;
    String SELECT;

    lecturer = new Lecturer();
    SELECT = "SELECT * FROM lecturer WHERE " + LECTURER_EMAIL + "= ?";
    try{
        PS_SELECT = myConn.prepareStatement(SELECT);
        PS_SELECT.setString(1, email);
        RS_SELECT = PS_SELECT.executeQuery();
        while (RS_SELECT.next()){
            lecturer.setProfilePicture(RS_SELECT.getBytes(LECTURER_PROFILE_PICTURE));
            lecturer.setProfilePictureCT(RS_SELECT.getString(LECTURER_PROFILE_PICTURE_CT));
            System.out.println("Lecturer Content Type is " + lecturer.getProfilePictureCT());
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lecturer;
}
```

Java Beans:

```
public class Lecturer {

private String email;
private String title;
private String name;
private String rank;
private char gender;
private String contactNumber;
private String contactMobile;
private byte[] profilePicture;
private String acctPassword;
private String acctStatus;
private String role;
private String supervisingAvailability;
private int bacherlorDegreeID;
private int programmeOfStudyID;
private String profilePictureCT;
```

Comment: It will work. But reading binaries in a high performance webapp from a database isn't a good idea. Better is to store it in a share filesystem.
btw: you forgot to close your statements